# Purpose of `tee >/dev/null` in Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, tee

What is the purpose of `tee` in Dockerfile lines such as:

```
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null
```

I am familiar with constructs of the form `... | sudo tee file >/dev/null`, but since the whole thing runs as root, there's no need for `sudo` here, and indeed there is no `sudo` before the `tee`. It's also not duplicating the output to stdout, since stdout is dumped to `/dev/null`.

So why not just do this:

```
RUN curl ... | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg
```

**NOTE:** I've noticed that in [that particular Dockerfile](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.2/Dockerfile), `tee` is only ever used after piping from `gpg --dearmor`. Other files are written directly as `... > file`. Could `gpg --dearmor` have something to do with why `tee` is needed?

Comment: `tee` is a cmd. Not specific to Docker. Check this article for more information, more or less it is a way to read standard input and provide multiple options for output: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/a-few-examples-of-using-the-tee-command

Comment: I know what `tee` is. I don't understand why it's needed in this context. It's not duplicating output, since stdout is discarded to `/dev/null`, and it's not escalating privileges, since the whole line runs as root already. The Dockerfile context is a) where I found this particular use case, and b) means the whole line runs as root.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg is dearmored and saved to /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg ?

As you say `.... | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg` should also work. It's is likely someone copied the `... | sudo tee file >/dev/null` form you know of and removed the sudo since they saw it unnecessary but didn't give it more thought and didn't realize the tee was also unnecessary.

Something like:

> Okay, I need this

> *Copy&paste*

> But without the sudo, this already runs as root

> *deletes sudo*

I don't think you need to overthink it.

Comment: Possible, but then other files in the same Dockerfile are written without `tee`. See my edit. If that was the process, I'd expect some `tee`s to be left over in the other commands too. But it's consistently either `output | gpg --dearmor | tee ...` or `output > file`.

Comment: @MichaelK: sounds like someone copy-and-pasted whatever worked ... consistent style or techniques is not a universally appreciated value.

Answer (score 0):

It's also of note that even if you need sudo, it's likely unnecessary to use tee, because gpg has an `--output file` / `-o file` option.

```
curl "$url" | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee "$file" >/dev/null
```

and

```
curl "$url" | sudo gpg -o "$file" --dearmor >/dev/null
```

Would produce the same file.